# Textual variants of “day of eternity” and exegesis of it (2 Peter 3:18)

Tags: textual-criticism, 2-peter

**Q: What is the definition of “**day of eternity**”?  And do enough
manuscripts support evidence for its inclusion?**

“but grow in the grace and knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ. To Him be the glory, both now and to the **day of eternity.** Amen.”
‭‭**2 Peter‬ ‭3:18‬** ‭NASB1995‬‬

Compare with different translation:

“but grow in the grace and knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ. To Him be the glory both now and forever. Amen.”
‭‭**II Peter‬ ‭3:18‬** ‭NKJV‬‬

Does day of eternity imply a single day that lasts forever, thus implying metaphor or figurative language?

Comment: Use block quotes and the hyperlink to the versions would be great. Use this site https://www.stepbible.org/?q=reference=2Pet.3.18|version=ESV|version=SBLG&options=GVUVNH&display=INTERLEAVED

Comment: YLT has 'to the day of the age' but Robert Young, here, has added an article to 'age' where there is none in the original. It would be interesting to know if this is the only occasion of the collocation in the Greek scriptures. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @Michael16 Are those “block quotes” a requirement or something?  Or just helpful?

Comment: Yes, everyone edits all questions to use the block quotes. It is customary. The hyperlink is very helpful, especially when it's about grammar/translation issue.

Comment: @Michael16 I’ll have to get used to that.  Got a lot going on.  Noted.

Answer (score 1):

The only significant textual variation in the MSS of 2 Peter 3:18 is whether the verse ends with "Amen" or not. For details about this variation, see UBS5.

As far as the phrase, εἰς ἡμέραν αἰῶνος = "in the day of eternity", there appears to be little dispute.  Thus, modern versions are divided between the translation:

- "in the day of eternity" (a literal translation) such as ESV, BSB, BLB, NASB, CSB, HCSB, LSV, etc
- "forever" (an interpretive translation) such as NIV, NLT, KJV, NKJV, CEV, GNT, ASV, NHEB, etc.

Now to the second question: How to understand the last half of the verse:

> αὐτῷ ἡ δόξα καὶ νῦν καὶ εἰς ἡμέραν αἰῶνος = to Him be the glory both now
> and to [the] day of eternity

This is simple Hebrew idiom meaning "from now until forever more".  This glory is "the glory" belonging exclusively to the One (John 17:5) is, now and continuously forever, as Ellicott observes:

> **To him be glory**.—Better, to Him be the glory—all that His creatures have to render. Whatever may be our view of 2 Peter 3:15,
> there can be no doubt that in this doxology homage is paid to Jesus
> Christ as true God. It is, perhaps, the earliest example of that “hymn
> to Christ as God” which Pliny tells Trajan the Christians were
> accustomed to sing before daybreak.
>
> **And for ever**.—Literally, and to the day of eternity. The phrase is used by the LXX. in Ecclesiasticus 18:10, but is found nowhere else in
> the New Testament. It means that day which marks the end of time and
> the beginning of eternity, the day which not only begins but is
> eternity. The expression is quite in harmony with the general drift of
> the chapter. “Heaven and earth shall pass away, but” “the day of God”
> “shall not pass away.”

Answer (score 0):

In light of OP's questions it
certainly helps to have a pattern of sound words as stated in 2 Timothy 1:13

A pattern of sound words is a word that is used consistently  in scripture.  Young's Translation of the word AION
is always consistently translated the same… it is defined as an age.

It does not help when you have inconsistency in words to assimilate what truth is being taught.  Many Translations will translate this word aion as eternal, never, world, age lasting, course.

◄ 165. aión ►
Strong's Concordance

> aión: a space of time, an age
> Original Word: αἰών, ῶνος, ὁ
> Part of Speech: Noun, Masculine
> Transliteration: aión
> Phonetic Spelling: (ahee-ohn')
> Definition: a space of time, an age

> Usage: an age, a cycle (of time), especially of the present age as contrasted with the future age, and of one of a series of ages stretching to infinity.

> Word-studies
> 165 aiṓn (see also the cognate adjective, 166 /aiṓnios, "age-long") – properly, an age (era, "time-span"), characterized by a specific quality (type of existence)

Here is the same verse from second Peter 3:18 translated in two other literal translations.

Literal Standard Version

> and increase in grace, and in the knowledge of our Lord and Savior Jesus Christ; to Him [is] the glory both now, and to the day of the age! Amen.

Young's Literal Translation

> and increase ye in grace, and in the knowledge of our Lord and Saviour Jesus Christ; to him is the glory both now, and to the day of the age! Amen.

Christ Glory has been seen on the mount of Transfiguration by a few of His disciples, probably by some of the prophets as well as Paul and in the hearts of believers by faith.
It will truly be seen in the day
of the next age when He will be physically manifested in Glory on this earth.

Is this is not the Lord's day talked  about in the previous verses?

It is also stated; remember, don't forget, Don't let it escape notice that a day With the Lord can be like a thousand years.  (Emphasis on the word  "with" is mine.)

> But do not forget this one thing, beloved, that one day is with the Lord as a thousand years, and a thousand years as one day.  2 Peter 3:8

Could that not be the millennial of 1000 year reign with Christ?

> it will come -- the day of the Lord -- as a thief in the night, in which the heavens with a rushing noise will pass away, and the elements with burning heat be dissolved, and earth and the works in it shall be burnt up.  2 Peter 3:10

The glory of Christ is coming to the earth. It is going to begin as a thief in the night, lasting for a  1000 years and ending when  all the works of the earth will be exposed and burned up.  That is the end of that age and will usher in the day of God, which is the new creation and another age begins.  This age is often called the age of the ages.

Comment: 2 Peter 3:18 uses the word aionios (eternal) in it.  I’m confused why you are using Aion.  I asked a bunch of people who know Greek what does Aionios mean, and they said “eternal”. Here is the link: https://www.quora.com/In-terms-of-the-etymology-of-both-%E1%BC%80%CE%90%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%BF%CF%82-and-%CE%B1%E1%BC%B0%CF%8E%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%BF%CE%BD-what-was-their-meaning-then-and-today-even-through-English-translations-of-the-Bible?ch=17&oid=116899479&share=30dde0bb&srid=uhU8E&target_type=question

Comment: @Cork88. Looking at the inter linear shows the word 165 aions which is we get our word eon or age from. 
ORIGIN OF AEON
1640–50; <Late Latin <Greek aiṓn space of time, age.
The Greek words aion and aionios, and the Hebrew equivalent olam, mean “age” and refer to a specific aeon, epoch or season. Although translated “eternal” and “everlasting”, they simply do not mean forever and ever.
The words aion, aionios and olam instead refer to a defined period of time dependent on the subject they describe. They can thus refer to short or long periods of time, but they  never mean unending,

Comment: nfinity, or forever and ever.  Here is a link that may be heipful in understanding the word aion that I just quoted from. https://abetterfuturenow.com/what-does-aionios-aion-eternal-mean/

Comment: Your sources are clearly denying the actual meaning of the words in order to better fit a bias.  The word Olam is used to describe God as “eternal” in Psalms 90:2, it can be used both as “age” or “eternal”.  In psalms 90:2 it cannot be “age” since God has no beginning or end: https://biblehub.com/psalms/90-2.htm         As I noted above, a had a bunch of people who know Greek show me that “Aionios” means eternal.  So I don’t follow that “Aionios” entails a limited amount of time.  It seems to me that you might be uncomfortable with such a teaching?

Comment: @Cork88. Believe me I understand where you're coming from!  It brings great joy, understanding and peace when one understands the ages and the purpose for them.   
It does require  a lot study though to see if these things are so.  One thing to keep in mind is eternal can never be the same as an age.  Eternal has no beginning and no end.  
In these last days did speak to us in a Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He did make the ages; Hebrews 1:2
Enough said on that subject for now.

Comment: Uh, the term “age enduring” means eternal and the term “eternal” comes from the Latin roots.  The Greek language expressed the word “eternal” with different terms than in Latin or English.  So I’m not sure I agree with your original premise. (from Latin aeternus "of an age, lasting, enduring, permanent, everlasting, endless,") source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/eternal